# How to securely sanitize permissions for a subtree

Tags: security, chmod, setuid, chgrp

On our server, there are multiple (currently two, expected three or four) users allowed to deploy a new version of our application. This process consists of downloading a few files from a trusted source git repository and starting the application (a non-privileged process).

This all gets done using a single script and takes a couple of seconds. Unless another user has left there files or directories with wrong permissions or group.

Then the deployment fails and we execute

```
sudo chgrp -R sudo      /our/root/directory
sudo chmod -R g=u,o-rwx /our/root/directory &&
```

I'd like to allow us to do this without the need to enter a password.

I know that `setuid` doesn't work on a shell script (for a good reason). I thought of using a setuid perl script, but it's no more supported. I could write a C wrapper and a script, but having two files sounds neither comfortable nor secure. I could write the whole stuff in C using system calls, but it'd take me ages.

So I'm asking: *What's a simple and secure way to achieve this?* Writing some short C code is OK.

It's Ubuntu 16.04 in case it matters.

---

(*) We're using the group `sudo` and permission `rwxrwx---` or `rw-rw----`  for the whole tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a shell script and give the applicable users permissions to invoke it with sudo. Use the `NOPASSWD` directive if you don't want the users to have to type their password (note that order matters, see [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)).

Make sure that sudo is set up to remove all variables from the environment except for a few safe ones (e.g. `LC_*` and `LANG`). This is the case by default on Ubuntu anyway, so on Ubuntu you don't need the `Defaults` line unless you've changed the `env_reset` setting.

```
Defaults!/usr/local/bin/fix-our-permissions env_reset
%our-app-maintainers ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/fix-our-permissions
```

---

Alternatively, have people access the deployment area through a filesystem that imposes fixed ownership and permissions, such as a [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/). See [Automatically change file permission upon write to a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52154/automatically-change-file-permission-upon-write-to-a-folder/52173#52173) and [All files created in directory should be owned by bob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261400/all-files-created-in-directory-should-be-owned-by-bob/261666#261666)

---

But really, nobody should be deploying manually. Deployment should be *triggered* manually, but it should be *performed* by an automated service which runs in a system user account, grabs a version from CI, downloads it and restarts the daemon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a programme wich monitor your folder, and if he find some trouble he change permission of folder or content, you do this in Crontab (root), or you run it as a service (root). this is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could change umask for those users to use the exact chmod that you want, this way every single archive they enter in the system would start with that defined set of permissions

leave you the link [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ACLs (`setfacl`); that may prevent the premission problems.

An alternative is that you download the files into a new, empty folder and replace the old one afterwards. This can be done atomically by overwriting a symlink to this folder (`ln -sf`).